# Textbox getting null after postback in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have below code and javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function FromCheckboxchange() {
    if ($("#chkFrom").is(":checked")) {
      $("#LocationFromCode").val("");
      $("#LocationFromCode").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
      $("#LocationFromCode").val("*****");
      $("#LocationFromCode").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }

  $(function () {
    $("#chkFrom").click(function (srcc) {
      FromCheckboxchange();
    });

    $("#chkTo").click(function (srcc) {
      ToCheckboxchange();
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="control-container">
  <span class="PopupLabel">From Location Code:</span><span> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocationFromCode, new { @class = "small" })</span>
  <span>
    @Html.CheckBox("chkFrom", new { @checked = "checked", @id = "chkFrom" })
  </span><span class="PopupLabel">To Location Code:</span><span> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocationToCode, new { @class = "small" })</span>
  <span>
    @Html.CheckBox("chkTo", new { @checked = "checked", @id = "chkTo" })
  </span>@*<span class="PopupLabel">Include:</span> *@<span class="switch-wrapper">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Exclude, new { @Class = "switch" })
  </span>
  <button type="submit" class="add-button" value="Add" />
</div>
```

When I uncheck the Location from code textbox value fills with "*****" and after that if I click on `submit` button the value of `LocationFromCode` getting `null`. and Also checkbox gets check again.
what is the wrong in above code ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes inside val()`$("#LocationFromCode").val("");`

Comment: I have removed the quotes from Val() but still getting the same problem.

Comment: by default both the checkboxes are checked when you uncheck it if condition is true so you get filled up with *,but where is your code to get the value while on clicking the submit button